# How to make user properties working in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I try to add my custom user properties to GA4
I created 2 of my user properties and I try to send them together with GA code but they dont show in analysis. The code

```
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXX"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'XXX');

        gtag('set', 'user_properties', {"my_prop1": "some value", "my_prop2": "some value2"});
    </script>
```